# Web Fonts não funcionam ao enviar e-mail com PHPMailer

Tags: php, css, phpmailer

Quando eu envio um email usando o PHPMailer as fontes não são reconhecidas pelo gmail, já estava ciente de alguns problemas com CSS e ter que user o css inline na tag "style", existe alguma forma de resolver isso?

Ex:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
<body style="margin: 0;padding: 0;background: #111;font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;;">
```

Comment: Acredito que a maior parte (quase todos) bloqueiem coisas externas como webfonts, ou seja, tags como `<link> ` e `<script>` não são permitidas. Todavia o teu script tem um erro `font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;` o certo seria `font-family: "Open Sans"`

Comment: Na verdade, isso foi gerado automaticamente por um conversor, porque está dentro de aspas, então não tem como usar fontes externas?

Comment: Não pois seria falha de segurança injetar coisas externas, todavia vou criar um teste para ver se é possivel converter em anexo.